# How to filter data from PagedListAdapter?

Tags: android, filter, adapter, android-architecture-components

I want to filter my `PagedListAdapter`
 like we filter in `RecyclerView.Adapter` using `Filter` class

```
public class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    private CustomFilter(RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // do filter stuff
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    }

}
```

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Can you please provide any example or link to refer